# Qt incomingConnections not called

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

I have compiled Qt's [Trip Planner example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405552&seqNum=3) that uses `QTcpSocket` and `QTcpServer` to create a client and server.

The problem is, the server's `incomingConnection()` slot is not being called. Even though the client connects to the server successfully. Therefore, the socket's `readyRead()` signal is never emitted and the client gets no data back.

**tripserver.cpp**

```
TripServer::TripServer(QObject *parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{
}


void TripServer::incomingConnection(int socketId)
{
    qDebug() << "Incoming Connection";
    ClientSocket *socket = new ClientSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketId);
}
```

If I add a newConnection() slot, it gets called. So what is going on?

Comment: May this help you http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52667-incommingConnection-not-called-by-QTcpServer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found my answer.

The parameter list has changed since Qt 4.8.1

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection

`void TripServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketId){}`

Comment: +1 This is really hard to debug, because if you leave it with the old signature, you just get a silent failure.

Comment: You made my day! My cross-platform app works perfectly on linux, windows, and android with the old signature...but not in iOS >= 11. To make it work there I had to use the qintptr socket descriptor...what a bad bug!

Comment: This is why you should always put `override` to an reimplemented member function. This will give a compile-time error, if you are not actually overriding something